How to lookup configuration for ALSA playback device?
Platform: NXP IMX8 nano
I'm learning how to program ALSA output by playing a wav file via aplay. Specifically, I'm trying to understand how the ALSA config files work. There are several and so far I've not found documentation on how to interpret the files and how they are used at runtime. So, one question is: where can I learn how to use/understand/extend the information in the ALSA config files?
The two config files that I find on my target board are usr/share/alsa/alsa.conf and /etc/asound.conf. They are 660 and 270 lines long, respectively. I think too long to include here :(
I know that aplay will play a wav file when I use a connection string (or whatever they're called in ALSA) that I find via aplay -L, but not via hw:#,# syntax. This works:
# aplay -D sysdefault:CARD=wm8524audio ~/wav/taunt.wav

But not this:
# aplay -D hw:3,0 ~/wav/taunt.wav
Playing WAVE '/root/wav/taunt.wav' : Unsigned 8 bit, Rate 22257 Hz, Mono
aplay: set_params:1387: Sample format non available
Available formats:
- S16_LE
- S24_LE
- S32_LE

I did try using each of the suggested formats with -f, like:
# aplay -D hw:3,0 ~/wav/taunt.wav -f S16_LE
Warning: format is changed to U8
Playing WAVE '/root/wav/taunt.wav' : Unsigned 8 bit, Rate 22257 Hz, Mono
aplay: set_params:1387: Sample format non available
Available formats:
- S16_LE
- S24_LE
- S32_LE

Don't know what "Warning: format is changed to U8" means. Might be relevant.
Taking a step back, I understand that the same device can be opened different ways and the connection string specifies a plugin or something.
How do I go about knowing what configuration settings apply to the longer name (sysdefault:CARD=wm8524audio)?
I searched both config files for "wm8524" but no match. Is there other ALSA configuration info on a system?
FYI:
# aplay -L
null
    Discard all samples (playback) or generate zero samples (capture)
sysdefault:CARD=btscoaudio
    bt-sco-audio, 30020000.sai-bt-sco-pcm-wb bt-sco-pcm-wb-0
    Default Audio Device
sysdefault:CARD=imxspdif
    imx-spdif, S/PDIF PCM snd-soc-dummy-dai-0
    Default Audio Device
sysdefault:CARD=wm8524audio
    wm8524-audio, HiFi wm8524-hifi-0
    Default Audio Device
# aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: btscoaudio [bt-sco-audio], device 0: 30020000.sai-bt-sco-pcm-wb bt-sco-pcm-wb-0 [30020000.sai-bt-sco-pcm-wb bt-sco-pcm-wb-0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: imxspdif [imx-spdif], device 0: S/PDIF PCM snd-soc-dummy-dai-0 [S/PDIF PCM snd-soc-dummy-dai-0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 3: wm8524audio [wm8524-audio], device 0: HiFi wm8524-hifi-0 [HiFi wm8524-hifi-0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 3: wm8524audio [wm8524-audio], device 1: HiFi-ASRC-FE (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

